# can't get http from tomcat on guest vm (nat connection)

Tags: linux, tomcat, nat

I have running centos on guest machine (using virtualbox, connection over nat).
And there's tomcat running on this machine on port 8080.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="0.0.0.0"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

There's port forwarding from host to guest
host 2222, guest 22 (ssh)
host 40001, guest 8080

I try to get page from http://localhost:8080
If I connect from host via ssh and do curl localhost:8080 I get an html page.

But if try to get http://localhost:40001 via browser, it becomes infinitely loading.
netstat -an | find "40001" on host machine shows
C:\Users\user>netstat -an | find "40001"

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:40001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:30279        127.0.0.1:40001        FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:40001        127.0.0.1:30279        CLOSE_WAIT
```

If I try to telnet on host machine (telnet localhost 40001) the connection is ok.

If I try to get a netstat on guest, I get this

```
[aegis@localhost ~]$ netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep tcp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

I can't figure out why telnet from host is working, but I can't get a page via browser. Could you help me, where I've made a mistake in configuration?

Comment: Do you see the telnet session on the guest netstat?

Comment: Hello, alnet. No, if I ask netstat -an | grep 8080, I get only
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: What port forwarding rule did you define in virtualbox? Does ssh host-->guest work?

Comment: two rules: tcp 2222->22 (ssh), it's working. tcp 40001->8080 is not working

Comment: I just not sure, is it ok that on my host machine I have netstat 40001 (listening), I wrote it in question before

Comment: Check in windows resource manager what application is listening to port 40001. Try to change the port... Put a simple telnet server on the guest.

Comment: every forwarded host port (2222, 40001) is listening by virtualbox.exe, changing forwarded port from 40001 to 40002 did nothing, it's working just like with 40001

Comment: Can you run tcpdump on the guest and check whether you receive any packets on that port? Try to understand whether you don't get packets into the guest at all or the problem with packets traveling back from the guest to the host.

Comment: There were problems with firewall. By default, 22 port is open, 8080 is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I was discaraged because of working "telnet localhost 40001 from host machine".
But there's difference between 22 and 8080 ports.

22 port is opened by default.
8080 port is not.
If you'll have such a problem, you should allow the firewall connection over 8080 port.

E.g., you can execute this statement:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```